# I want to input date calculated Year and month show two text box like txtYear and txtMonth

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

The date time picker on  then input date make difference from system date that Year and month show two text box like txtYear and txtMonth.

In short, I input a date two textboxes will show calculated value as how many year and month.

Comment: "as how many year and month", of what exactly?

Comment: please put in the code that you tried...:)

Comment: Yes C# and Javascript.

Comment: I wanted to make difference between system date to input date, text boxes will show calculated value as how many year and month.

Comment: Do you mean the offset between the two dates in years and months?

Comment: Yes, Mr.  Romano Zumbé